# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS on Pixhawk

Tags: ros, pixhawk

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Has anyone tried to link ROS and Pixhawk together? I am trying to use ros functions to do something like this :

http://wiki.ros.org/openni/Contests/ROS%203D/Autonomous%20corridor%20flight%20of%20a%20UAV%20using%20the%20Kinect%20sensor.

Pixhawk : http://store.3drobotics.com/products/3dr-pixhawk

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/198015/ros-on-pixhawk/) by [itskeeho](https://answers.ros.org/users/20670/itskeeho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To bring these things together install [mavros](http://wiki.ros.org/mavros) which is basically a [MAVProxy](http://tridge.github.io/MAVProxy/). To learn how it works see [here](http://dev.ardupilot.com/wiki/odroid-via-mavlink/).

---

Originally posted by [Pat](https://answers.ros.org/users/20010/pat/) with karma: 62 on 2015-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0